# What is return value of CvMLData::read_csv?

Tags: opencv, opencv-ml

The documentation doesn't mention it: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/mldata.html
Is it number of read lines or OK/ERROR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their code doc mentioned with the function header in `ml.hpp`, it returns OK/ERROR.

```
// returns:
// 0 - OK
// -1 - file can not be opened or is not correct
```

Comment: OK, thanks! I hope you don't use it any more. Very old stuff. Btw, do you have a link to the sources returning defines? The one I found returns 0 and -1 : https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/apps/traincascade/old_ml_data.cpp